# How to get the value and not the memory address in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, random, memory-address

I am a beginner and I am trying to get a random value from a function that I created that uses a package containing four python files and an **init** file. Each file works independently and has been imported, successfully, elsewhere as a module.
I have tried other things from the random library such as sample, choices and randint. I am getting a random output at the moment, but, it is just the memory address.

**This is the output that I get when I run the program.**

```
<function Syll4 at 0x7fccf9ff0b80>
```

**This is what the desired outcome looks like.**

```
All presence are contest
All past are presence
All past are contest
```

**This is the problem code**:

```
import random
     
import multi_syllogisms
     
    
     def main():
         a = multi_syllogisms.Syll1
         b = multi_syllogisms.Syll2
         c = multi_syllogisms.Syll3
         d = multi_syllogisms.Syll4
   
         x = [a, b, c, d]
         print(random.choice(x))
   
   
main()
```

multi_syllogisms is a folder containing four .py files plus an **init**.py. Each file generates a type of syllogism, randomly.

**This is file 4, they are all similar:**

```
import random
def Syll4():
    # variables = lists go here.
    
while True:
        a = (random.choice(noun1))
        b = (random.choice(noun2))
        c = (random.choice(noun3))
  
        print(x+a+y+b)
        print(x+c+y+a)
        print(x+c+y+b)
        return ""
        break
```

Comment: Please show the code in `multi_syllogisms`.  The code you've shown should produce *no* output by itself.  I'm guessing that there are some `print`s inside of that module, which will happen regardless of the result of `randome.choice`.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. We have no idea what `multi_syllogisms` is, and therefore cannot reproduce your problem or offer help on how to fix it. Please take the [tour], and read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask],
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: I refresh this page to see if there are any new suggestions. Every time I do this the number of views increases. This gives the false impression that more people have looked at this problem and have failed to answer it than actually have. So as of 24/7/2022 you need to subtract about 10 from the number of views shown at the top of this page to get a better idea of what is going on here.